# How to generate random binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

I am given a list of labels `L` and I wish to **recursively** generate a **random** binary tree from `L`.

The desired behavior is like this:

`generate(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])`

could give:

`((('A', ('B', 'C')), ('D', 'E')), 'F')`

Note that the list of leaf labels from left to right should equal `L`.

I am in doubt how to *randomly construct* the tree. This is what I have so far (I split the list of labels at a random index.

```
def generate_tree(L):
    split = randint(1, len(L)-1)
    left = L[:split]
    right = L[split:]

    # call generate(left) and generate(right) based on some conditions
```

I am stuck. I would be grateful for a couple of hints or help.

Comment: your binary tree doesn't look random

Comment: @kederrac What do you mean? I haven't generated one yet. The example I provided is just an example of a *possible* output.

Comment: @kederrac Since the list of leaf labels from left to right should equal `L`, I guess you could say it's not completely random.

Comment: Why don't you randomize the ordering? even if it has to be an ordered tree you can randomize insertion order

Comment: is fine if the result is nested list and not tuples ?

Comment: The leaf labels in your example aren't `L`! `'A'` is in `L`, but not a leaf in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren' too far off. All you needed was a base case and building the resulting tuple from the results of the recursive calls:

```
def generate_tree(L):
    # base case
    if len(L) == 1: 
        return L[0]
    split = randint(1, len(L)-1)
    left = L[:split]
    right = L[split:]
    # recursion
    return (generate_tree(left), generate_tree(right))

>>> generate_tree(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
(('A', 'B'), (('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')))
>>> generate_tree(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
((('A', 'B'), 'C'), (('D', 'E'), 'F'))
>>> generate_tree(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
('A', (('B', 'C'), (('D', 'E'), 'F')))
```

And if you are code golfing and looking for a fancy (>=3.8 only) one-liner:

```
def gt(L):
    return (gt(L[:(s:=randint(1, len(L)-1))]), gt(L[s:])) if len(L) > 1 else L[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can randomly slice the list and then recursively apply the tree construction:

```
import random
def r_tree(d):
   _l, _r = tuple(d[:(_n:=random.randint(0, len(d)-1))]), tuple(d[_n+1:])
   l, r = _l if len(_l) < 3 else r_tree(_l), _r if len(_r) < 3 else r_tree(_r)
   return (d[_n], n[0] if len(n:=tuple(filter(None, [l, r]))) == 1 else n)

print(r_tree(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']))
```

Output:

```
('D', (('A', ('B', 'C')), ('E', 'F')))
```

Comment: IMHO this answer would gain a lot if the code were a bit less dense...